# Can I limit total cputime used by a cgroup?

Tags: linux

Although cgroups seemingly allow to control the CFS bandwidth of a cgroup, I don't see a way of enforcing a cpu time limit on a cgroup. The use case is that I would like to catch student programs that e.g. go into an infinite loop.

Comment: I solved this with getrlimit(2) (to limit CPU time per process, which are inherited by its children) and limits.conf(5) (to limit forking, which is a good idea anyhow). But this is not very fine grained.

Comment: Please, take a time and post your comment as an answer and accept it :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the information from [this Red Hat page](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Resource_Management_Guide/sec-cpu.html) if you want to stick to Control Groups, but I think your `ulimit` solution is a reasonable approach and doesn't require the configuration that cgroups would require (just add one command to `/etc/profile` and you're good).